# Regular expression to remove spaces and replace newline separators

Tags: regex, newline, spaces

Is it possible to replace a character sequence with a newline (\s~\s in this example) and also remove spaces in the beginning and at the end with one regular expression? The number of lines must be flexible.

Input:

```
    foo = 1 ~ bar = 2 ~ baz = 3 ~ ...     <- also spaces at the end
```

Desired output:

```
foo = 1
bar = 2
baz = 3
... <- no spaces here
```

I got it working so far, the problem is that my result still has the spaces at the end of the last line:

My current regex search and replace (https://regexr.com/444au):

```
# search 
/(\s*)([^~\s]{1}.*?)(\s~\s)(?=.*)(\s*)/g

# replace
$2\n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to alternate between the `\s~\s` and `\s+$`, thereby *matching* the trailing spaces at the very end:

```
\s*([^~\s].*?)(?:\s~\s+|\s+$)
```

replace with

```
$1\n
```

https://regexr.com/4452l

Note that since the only group you actually care about is the one with `[^~\s]{1}.*?`, you can remove all other capturing groups. `{1}` is a meaningless quantifier, so you can remove that as well, and `(?=.*)` won't do anything - *any position* in the string *will* be followed by *zero or more* characters regardless, so feel free to remove that lookahead.